# Laravel Routing Parameter Contraint

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, constraints

Been working on a neat little project. I'm using Laravel 5.5, and I'm building routes to handle the various requests. I've got a route that accepts a slug to locate a particular guild via route model binding. Works great! Beautifully, actually. Then, I defined a "static" route that doesn't use a parameter to show the form for creating a new guild. Here's the routes...

```
Route::get('/guilds', 'GuildController@index')->name('guilds');
Route::get('/guild/{guild}', 'GuildController@show')->name('guild');
Route::get('/guild/create', 'GuildController@create')->name('create_guild');
Route::get('/guild/{guild}/edit', 'GuildController@edit')->name('edit_guild');
Route::post('/guild/create', 'GuildController@store')->name('store_guild');
```

But when I attempt to navigate to '/guild/create', I get a 404 because a guild with the slug "create" doesn't exist. How can I work around this particular issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try put specific routes first:

```
Route::get('/guilds', 'GuildController@index')->name('guilds');
Route::get('/guild/create', 'GuildController@create')->name('create_guild');
Route::post('/guild/create', 'GuildController@store')->name('store_guild');
Route::get('/guild/{guild}', 'GuildController@show')->name('guild');
Route::get('/guild/{guild}/edit', 'GuildController@edit')->name('edit_guil');
```